# Total and percentage for each column in a line and stacked column chart

Tags: tooltip, powerbi, linechart

I need to show in one single bar chart the number of elements of each column and also its percentage regarding the total.

With a Line and stacked columns chart, I reach this:

[image]

However, the tooltip option, on the line, shows me only one value, and I need to get both of them. I mean, not only that 32 but also the percentage corresponding to that value.

Is there a way to get this? maybe another chart?

Comment: Can you not just add a measure for the number to the tooltips section?

Comment: Hi Alexis. The customer requires to see the number and the percentage for each section of the column. That is why the measure as % of grand total has been added to the tooltip option. I just need to figure it out how show these two values for the total of each column.

Comment: So just add whatever additional measure you want to the tooltip. You aren't limited to one field.

Comment: I have updated the image. That is what I am trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I understand the question now. Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible.

[From Microsoft Community Support](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Tooltips-doesn-t-work-in-line-values-in-line-and-stacked-column/td-p/334043),

> This is an expected behavior. The tooltips only show when you hover over a column data point in combo chart.

This has been submitted as an idea for Microsoft to address. Please vote and/or comment here:

[Combo Charts: How to add tooltip on line](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34579048-combo-charts-how-to-add-tooltip-on-line)

Comment: Ok thaks for your answer alexis